# (Rails 4) Acts_as_taggable_on: using a model other than "Tag"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to implement the acts_as_taggable_on gem. In my set up I have a Model called Discipline which is pre-populated with about 40 names.

I also have a Model Micropost which I want to tag - using a select box containing all the names in the disciplines database. I thought that I could call the acts_as_taggable_on the Model I wanted - in this case Disciplines but its not working with my current set up.

```
   class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
         acts_as_taggable 
         acts_as_taggable_on :disciplines  
    end
```

Here is the form......

```
     <%= simple_form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
     <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

     <%= f.input :tag_list, :as => :select,
              :multiple => :true,
              :collection => ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.pluck(:name) %>

     <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What is your question?", :style => "height:75px;" %>
     <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
     <% end %>
```

I can tell from the documentation that there is a way to do this....but I guess I am just not getting it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I want to use this for a similar purpose

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use acts_as_taggable_on using a model other than the default Tag and Taggings models.

**Alternative Approach #1**
Seed your database with the pre-populated 40 Tags containing your discipline names.

**Alternative Approach #2**
Use [bitmask_attributes](https://github.com/joelmoss/bitmask_attributes) for your 40 disciplines.
For example, in my application I have:

```
bitmask :instruments, as: [:others, :guitar, :piano, :bass, :mandolin, :banjo,
                               :ukulele, :violin, :flute, :harmonica, :trombone,
                               :trumpet, :clarinet, :saxophone, :viola, :oboe,
                               :cello, :bassoon, :organ, :harp, :accordion, :lute,
                               :tuba, :ocarina], null: false
```